# I can not quit Unity Editor, only force quit

Tags: unity-game-engine

> OS X 10.11.5
>
> Unity 5.3.4p1

Every time I use command + q to quit my project or File-> Open Project, Unity stop working, it seems everything is freezed with mac loading ball below.

The only way out is to force quit.

Can you help me? Can you just give me a way to solve this

This really makes me crazy!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug that has been fixed in 5.4 beta According to Unity release notes.

> Fixed issue whereby the launcher could crash on exit.

Download [Unity 5.40B19](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta) and this problem should gone.

Comment: Good one.  Also, this can be caused simply by an infinite loop in your code - I'm always doing this!  Turn off components one at a time until you find the problem, or, write loops more carefully.

Comment: @JoeBlow He said it freeze when he go to  File-> Open Project or try to quit project not play mode. When your loop code freezes Unity, you won't even be able to go to  File-> Open Project at all. To him it happens when he closes Unity or go to  File-> Open Project. Maybe I am wrong